# Socket.io Node Laravel Redis and saving chat messages to database

Tags: php, node.js, sockets

I have a laravel project that uses Node Laravel and Redis to make a real time chat. I have followed many tuturials however I am lost on how to save the data from the chat to my messages database(MySql). I've seen this tuturial where you can use Redis to broadcast events with laracasts, and also this youtube video that uses MongoDB https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c01OHDUpDMU.I havent been able to find a clear answer on any saving methods for socket. Do I need to send a ajax request outside of the socket??

Here I tried to make a test HttpRequest, maybe there is someway to send the data over a post request to my Laravel Route?

Can anyone provide advice?

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

server.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
});

console.log('chat has booted...');

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('join', function (data) {
        socket.userId = data.user_id;
        socket.userName = data.user_name;
        socket.class_group = data.class_group;
        console.log('User ' + socket.userName + ' is now available');
    });

    //notify connected users availability

    socket.on('notify', function (notice) {
        console.log( notice + ' from' + ' user ' + socket.userName );
        io.emit('receive note.' + notice[0], 'hello');
    })

    socket.on('subscribe', function (room) {
        console.log('joining room', room);
        socket.join(room);
    })

    socket.on('send', function(data){
        console.log(socket.userName + ': ' + data.message + ' to room' + '[' + data.room + ']');
            io.to(data.room).emit('message', data);
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', "http://google.com", true); //Here I tried to make a test HttpRequest, maybe there is someway to send the data over a post request to my Laravel Route?
    });
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        console.log('user disconnected');
    });
});
```

Comment: Sorry but people have to pay to get access to the link you provided. Are you trying to save messages to Laravel?

Comment: ah crap i forgot about that. Yes i want to be able to save the message to my database when the message is sent. I was thinking about making a seperate ajax request but I figured there should be a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, the script you posted is Node.js script that will be executed on server side.

In order to save to MongoDB you can use MongoDB driver: https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native